# Life expectancy of a CXY-B1 Li-ion battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

Last year I got a National Geographic Explorer 4 camera with two CXY-B1 Li-ion batteries (3.7V, 1000 mAh 3.7Wh). In one year, I used them both for about 7 hours in total over the course of the year (calculated from the size of saved footage and average bit-rate).

After charging them both overnight, one of them now turns on for a second before turning off, the other shows the warning sign of low battery.

Is this normal? What is the life expectancy of such batteries?

**Update**: Following the comments, the first battery has a voltage of 3.7V and
the second has 2.5V. After 5 hours in the charger, they have 3.7V and 4.2V
(yes, 4.2V, and yet this battery fails to turn on the camera). I have often brought these batteries to well below 60%, as my filming sessions lasted longer than 2 battery lives.

Comment: Sounds like a faulty charger.

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter? you could check the battery voltage & the voltage out of the charger. The storage life of batteries heavily depends on the state of the battery during the storage period, if it was totally drained that’s not good, most batteries recommend a voltage for storage normally somewhere around 60%-80% of fully charged voltage.

Comment: www.batteryuniversity.com and many others say that your storage voltage of 60% is way too low and damages the battery. A storage voltage of 3.8V per cell is good. Damage begins at 3.2V per cell.

Comment: I updated the question. Back in the day with Nokia 3310 phones we were advised to drain the battery completely before recharging. Was that a different type of battery or was that advice also misguided then?